# Analytic map zero on open subset set is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

**Claim.** Given an analytic map $f$ on a connected open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and an open set $S$ such that $f(S)=\{0\}$, then $f=0$.

**Proof.** I define $Z=\{z\in U:f(z)=0\}$, then if I prove that $Z$ is both open and closed in $U$, it follows that $Z=U$ and we are done.
I've already proved the closeness.

$Z$ is open: how to I proceed? My scattered thoughts

1. I now that two analytic maps that agree on a set with accumulation point $z$, are equal on some neighborhood of $z$
2. on one side if $Z$ is not open there is a point $z$ such that every open neighborhood  meets $U-Z$; is this a contradiction? Not yet.
3. At some point I have to use $S$. But the openness is a local thing (interior point)
4. The connection between local and global could be done using a path (supposing that open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is path-connected iff connected; or it is valid for general metric space, I miss some result here)

> Q: How to I prove that $Z$ is open?

Note: At the end it is the [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), I think. But I would like to avoid the use of Taylor and derivatives. 
My feeling is that it should be possible with pure topological steps and using (1).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: If you can use that two analytic maps that agree on a set with accumulation point are equal then it is trivial. Any open set has an accumulation point.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Your link is exactly the same as the one in my post

Comment: @MohamedAli The identity theorem is also proved using connectedness, the way you are trying to prove. I don't think you can discover simpler proof.

Comment: No the two proofs  are not the same! In the proof that actually works, instead of your $Z$ we havve the set $Z_\omega$, consisting of all the points where $f$ _and every derivative of_ $f$ vanishes! (The proof that $Z_\omega$ is closed is the same as the proof that $Z$ is closed; the difference is it's easy to show  $Z_\omega$ is open.)

Answer (score 1):

Using $(1)$ a purely topological proof is possible:

Let $Z$ be the zero set of $f$ and $X$ be the set of all points in $D$, which are accumulation points of $Z$.

Since the limit of a convergent sequence of accumulation points of $Z$ is a accumulation point of $Z$, $X$ is closed in $D$. By $(1)$ (applied to $f$ and the the zero function), $X$ is open in $D$. Since $f\equiv 0$ on a nonempty open subset, $X\neq \emptyset$.

Hence by connectedness of $D$, $X=D$, so each point in $D$ is an accumulation point of the zero set of $f$. By continuity of $f$ (or again by $(1)$) $f\equiv 0$ on $D$.